# How to specify arrow coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

i tried to draw an arrow from (0.1,0.5) to (0.5,0.5) in matplotlib based on this example (http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/arrow_simple_demo.html):

```
f = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.ylim([0, 1])
ax.arrow(0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
         head_width=0.05,
         head_length=0.1,
         fc='k',
         ec='k',
         clip_on=False)
plt.show()
```

this should produce a horizontal arrow but for some reason it gives a slanted arrow that doesn't end in (0.5,0.5). what is wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [`Axes.arrow`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.arrow.html) and [`pyplot.arrow`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.arrow.html):

> ```
> .arrow(x, y, dx, dy, hold=None, **kwargs)
> ```
>
> Add an arrow to the axes.
>
> Call signature:
>
> ```
> arrow(x, y, dx, dy, **kwargs)
> ```
>
> Draws arrow on specified axis from `(x, y)` to `(x + dx, y + dy)`. Uses FancyArrow patch to construct the arrow.

So, in your arrow, you have:

```
x = 0.1, 
y = 0.5, 
dx = 0.5, 
dy = 0.5
```

Thus, you will draw an arrow from `(0.1,0.5)` to `(0.6,1.0)`.

Set `dy=0` and you will get a horizontal arrow. To get an arrow from `(0.1,0.5)` to `(0.5,0.5)`, you need:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlim(0, 0.6)
ax.set_ylim(0.45, 0.55)

ax.arrow(0.1, 0.5, 0.4, 0.0)
```

[image]